# MS Access - SubForm field pass through

Tags: database, forms

I have a Navigation Form in which the first button is defaulted to show a blank form (Request form) where users will enter information.

There's an option on this Request form that if there are multiple requests under this request, `a box is checked and another form opens and the request number from the Request form is defaulted into the multiple request form's request number field (this is the link).

On the Multiple Request window's ID field in Property Sheet/Data/Default Value I have =[Forms]![frmRequests]![RequestID]

With the Request form open on its own, this works great, but within the Navigation form it doesn't. Is there another layer that I need to add so the default value works in either format?  I will be using it in the Navigation form primarily.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
=Forms!NavigationFormName.NavigationSubformName.Form!RequestID
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).